# Change value when view is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates

I have a NowPlayingVC, as a child of my MainVC(a collection view), I'd like to change a textValue inside the NowPlayingVC when a third viewcontroller (SingleSoundVC) get dismissed.
I do everything via code, and I cant understand why my labels are still not visible after the dismiss.
If I try hard coding they work just fine, but never change.

[image: nowPlayingVC]

I can print correctly when the third views gets dismissed but the label is empty, even though I can see it with the debug view hierarchy.

I tried with Protocol/Delegate like this:

**Protocol**

```
protocol SendDataToAudioPlayerContainer {
func receiveData(data:Sound){
     self.audioNameLabel.text = data.name
   }
}
```

**NowPlayingVC**

```
NowPlayingVC: SendDataToAudioPlayerContainer
     var audioNameLabel:UILabel = {
        var lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.numberOfLines = 0
        lbl.textAlignment = .left
        lbl.sizeToFit()
        lbl.textColor = .black
        return lbl
    } 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
  func setupViews() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.view.addSubview(audioNameLabel)
}
 func setupConstraints(){ //setup of constraints with SnapKit}
```

}

**SingleSoundVC**

```
var delegate:SendDataToAudioPlayerContainer?
var singleSound: Sound?
@objc func dismissView(){

    if self.delegate != nil {
        print("data passed up")
        let data = self.singleSound
        delegate?.receiveData(data: data!)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("data is not passed")}

}
```

I also have to add that when I select the item I added NowPlaying as the delegate of MainVC

**MainVC - CollectionView**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = MainVC()
    let childVC = NowPlayingVC()
    vc.delegate = childVC
    ApiService.sharedInstance.downloadAudioFile(with: vc.singleSound!.audioId)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Upload your code to Github to help you get better

Comment: Why you are setting `vc.delegate = childVC`? you should set the `SingleSoundVC` delegate to `NowPlayingVC`

Answer (score 0):

**MainVC - CollectionView**

you should create a property for NowPlayingVC to reference to the same instance:
var nowPlayingVC = NowPlayingVC()

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = SingleSoundVC()
    vc.delegate = nowPlayingVC
    ApiService.sharedInstance.downloadAudioFile(with: vc.singleSound!.audioId)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Protocol**

should be defined as:

```
    protocol SendDataToAudioPlayerContainer {
        func receiveData(data:Sound)
    }
```

**NowPlayingVC**

adopt it to `SendDataToAudioPlayerContainer` protocol :
add

```
func receiveData(data:Sound){
         self.audioNameLabel.text = data.name
         **// update constraints here**
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly what you told me, but even if I can pass the data correctly, the label doesn't update. I tried to add the same label to the NowPlaying view via addSubView but from the memory I can see that it adds it somewhere else.

Comment: it could be that the way I initialize my audioNameLabel is wrong? i initialize it like :     `var nameLabel:UILabel = {
        var lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.textAlignment = .left
        lbl.sizeToFit()
        lbl.text = "This is text"
        lbl.textColor = .black
        lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Cabin-Regular", size: 16)
        return lbl
    }()`

Comment: I think that anytime i dismiss my controller It creates a new UILABEL

Comment: Actually NowPlayingVC is still in memory when you present SingleSoundVC, so the label is created just once. The issue is that `lbl.sizeToFit()` doesn't give you anything and the width and height are still 0. You should update the constraints after `func receiveData(data:Sound){` is called to fit the text properly or just call self.audioNameLabel.sizeToFit() depending on how you layout the label. it depends on you implementation in `func setupConstraints()`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am trying to print the nameLabel, but i see 2 different codes in memory. I tried anything, to add the subview in the delegate method, to update the constraints, but nothing... i am starting to think this is a bug in SnapKit or XCode...

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is a NowPlaying like spotify or apple music. I also tried to create a UIView instead of adding a child view controller to my main view, but i find can't properly initialize and set the constraints correctly...